# select nth-child from 1st to 4th

Tags: css, css-selectors

I which to reach the 4th first child.
is there a better syntax than?

```
footer div:first-child, footer div:nth-child(2), footer div:nth-child(3), footer div:nth-child(4)  {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Here we go

`code`
    <footer>
     <div>To reach</div>
     <div>To reach</div>
     <div>To reach</div>
     <div>To reach</div>
     <div>Not</div>
     <div>Not</div>
     <div>Not</div>
     <div>Not</div>
    </footer>`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a better syntax.

The selector you're looking for is: `:nth-child(-n + 4)`

Here's a demo:

```css
.wpr {}

.wpr div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wpr div:nth-child(-n + 4) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

See [MDN - nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

> `:nth-child(-n+3)`
>
> Represents the first three elements among a group of siblings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer